# how to mux a multi-slice h264 stream via android mediamuxer

Tags: android, x264

I'm trying to mux a mp4 file using mediaMuxer. I've already set SPS, PPS and replaced the 4-bit header. When the h.264 frame formed with single slice, everything is ok, but when I change it into multi-slice, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

sounds multi-slice is not fully supported in android mediaMuxer, it will cause compatible issue when plays on iPhone/QuickTime player.